# Is the Java Memory Model only Java-wide or actually JVM-wide?

Tags: java, jvm, java-memory-model

I see it always referred as the Java-Memory-Model, yet hitherto I instinctively thought of it as applicable to the whole JVM ecosystem.

Is it applicable only between Java created applications, or does any bytecode JVM-compliant executable also enjoy from its guarantees?

I've looked up on the JVM spec by "Memory model" and couldn't find that much about it. On the other hand, the java spec thoroughly describes it, leaving me with the impression that the memory model is Java specific..

Thanks

Comment: Cannot provide deep technical explanations but my understanding is that any generated bytecode regardless of the language will run in a JVM with all it implies in terms of referencial abstraction, type safety, sandboxing...

Comment: To be fair, there are references to the JLS (Java Language Speciifcation) throughout the JVM spec, so what you're saying may well be the case.

Comment: Most of the guarantees of the memory model must be provided by the JVM. But some require the compiler to cooperate - there are some optimisations it can't do (e.g. reordering operations). But any sane language targeting the JVM should provide the equivalent of the guarantees of the Java Memory Model.

Answer (score 4):

Technically the Java memory model targets Java only and refers to Java constructs (synchronized, volatile, final...). But the enforcement of the JMM is delegated to the JVM through specific bytecode instructions.

For example, synchronized blocks translate into monitorenter / monitorexit bytecode instructions.

So any JVM compatible language can in theory define a specific memory model (as long as it can be described based on the JMM) and produce appropriate bytecode.

In practice, there are some direct equivalences, such as Scala's `@volatile` or Clojure's `volatile-mutable`.